# StackOverflow for Android Samsung GalaxyTab 7.0 (SCH-I800)

Tags: android

I have an app that seems to be generating StackOverflow Exceptions for some (all?) SCH-I800 devices.

Stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1930)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see there isn't a single line of my own app in there. So I'm not sure where to even start digging. It definitely crashes for several SCH-I800 devices. They are mainly Android 2.3.5 but at least one is 2.3.6.

It crashes mutliple times for each device.

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm not sure where to even start digging.

Well, the stack trace suggests that this occurs when a service is being created:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1930)
```

Looking at the source code for that method, the most likely circumstance that would result in this stack trace is that there is a problem in the constructor of the service. I am assuming that your code is working on other devices, given the nature of your question, so there is something in the service construction phase that is tripping over a bug in the SCH-I800 firmware.

Comment: OK, well yes I'd got that far :-), and yes it's working happily for all other devices.

I do use an IntentService, but it is bog standard.

Comment: @William: Seems odd that `IntentService` would generally crash on this device, though. Could you post the constructor of your `IntentService`?

Comment: public GeneralIntentService() { super("GeneralIntentService"); }

Its a simple service only 80 lines.

Full listing: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DrM4tfeP_nuPprc81JiQMnqwGlY2qBILnYQbPwR3uRw

Comment: @William: That document appears to be empty. Regardless, that constructor seems perfectly normal, but there's no way that it is going to crash just from that. I'm stumped.

Comment: Sorry that URL should be https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DrM4tfeP_nuPprc81JiQMnqwGlY2qBILnYQbPwR3uRw/edit